# How to set the matplotlib figure default size in ipython notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I use "$ipython notebook --pylab inline" to start the ipython notebook.  The display matplotlib figure size is too big for me, and I have to adjust it manually.  How to set the default size for the figure displayed in cell?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

I believe the following work in version 0.11 and above. To check the version:

```
$ ipython --version
```

It may be worth adding this information to your question.

Solution:

You need to find the file `ipython_notebook_config.py`. Depending on your installation process this should be in somewhere like

```
.config/ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py
```

where `.config` is in your home directory.

Once you have located this file find the following lines

```
# Subset of matplotlib rcParams that should be different for the inline backend.
# c.InlineBackend.rc = {'font.size': 10, 'figure.figsize': (6.0, 4.0), 'figure.facecolor': 'white', 'savefig.dpi': 72, 'figure.subplot.bottom': 0.125, 'figure.edgecolor': 'white'}
```

Uncomment this line `c.InlineBack...` and define your default figsize in the second dictionary entry.

Note that this could be done in a python script (and hence interactively in IPython) using

```
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.0, 8.0)
```

Comment: In ipython 2.0 the config file is in .ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py

Comment: In older versions of iPython, `ipython_notebook_config.py` doesn't contain the line to configure the inline backend. Since the configuration file is not automatically updated when you update iPython (at least on Windows), you need to delete it and generate a new config file by running `ipython profile create` as suggested by @anmol below.

Comment: You can locate existing profiles with `ipython profile locate`.

Comment: And if you're using matplotlib instead of pyplot, the interactive command is    ```matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.0, 8.0)```

Comment: I'm using jupyter 4.1.0-6 with python-ipykernel 4.5.2-3 and ipython 5.3.0-1 (all of them on Arch) and I have no file titled `ipython_notebook_config.py` under my `~`. Any idea how things may have changed in the most recent versions?

Comment: If you are using jupyter notebook, update `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py` instead of `~.ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py`

Answer (score 159):

Worked liked a charm for me:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20, 10)
```

Comment: I don't know how idiomatic this is, but I adjusted this for my jupyter notebook to get it to work:
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
`%matplotlib inline`
`plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20.0, 10.0)`

Comment: There is also `plt.rc('figure', figsize=(20.0, 10.0))`

Comment: Quite weird, but after some update I need to split `%matplotlib inline` and `plt.rc(...)` across different cells for the latter to work. Same true for `matplotlib.rcParams[...]`

Comment: Also make sure this line is after `%matplotlib inline`

Answer (score 21):

If you don't have this ipython_notebook_config.py file, you can create one by following the readme and typing

```
ipython profile create
```

Answer (score 21):

Just for completeness, this also works

```
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize
figsize(14, 7)
```

It is a wrapper aroung the `rcParams` solution

Comment: Important for a large notebook with multiple plots, and works like a charm

Answer (score 8):

In iPython 3.0.0, the inline backend needs to be configured in `ipython_kernel_config.py`. You need to manually add the `c.InlineBackend.rc`... line (as mentioned in [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2145647/greg)'s answer). This will affect both the inline backend in the Qt console and the notebook.

Answer (score 8):

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ["run commands"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67180265/9067615) `rc` to change the default figure size:

```py
plt.rc('figure', figsize=(w,h))
```

Answer (score 0):

So, a working solution on macos is

```
echo "
c.InlineBackend.rc = {
         'font.size': 10,
         'figure.figsize': (25.0, 5.0),
         'figure.facecolor': 'white', 
         'savefig.dpi': 72,
         'figure.subplot.bottom': 0.125,
         'figure.edgecolor': 'white'
}
" >> "$(ipython locate profile)/ipython_kernel_config.py"
```