# Plot width settings in ipython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I've got the following plots:

[image: sound signals]

It would look nicer if they have the same width. Do you have any idea how to do it in ipython notebook when I am using `%matplotlib inline`?

**UPDATE:**

To generate both figures I am using the following functions:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show_plots2d(title, plots, points, xlabel = '', ylabel = ''):
    """
    Shows 2D plot.

    Arguments:
        title : string
            Title of the plot.
        plots : array_like of pairs like array_like and array_like
            List of pairs,
            where first element is x axis and the second is the y axis.
        points : array_like of pairs like integer and integer
            List of pairs,
            where first element is x coordinate
            and the second is the y coordinate.
        xlabel : string
            Label of x axis
        ylabel : string
            Label of y axis
    """
    xv, yv = zip(*plots)
    y_exclNone = [y[y != np.array(None)] for y in yv]
    y_mins, y_maxs = zip(*
        [(float(min(y)), float(max(y))) for y in y_exclNone]
    )
    y_min = min(y_mins)
    y_max = max(y_maxs)
    y_amp = y_max - y_min
    plt.figure().suptitle(title)
    plt.axis(
        [xv[0][0], xv[0][-1], y_min - 0.3 * y_amp, y_max + 0.3 * y_amp]
    )
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    for x, y in plots:
        plt.plot(x, y)
    for x, y in points:
        plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
    plt.show()

def show_plot3d(title, x, y, z, xlabel = '', ylabel = '', zlabel = ''):
    """
    Shows 3D plot.

    Arguments:
        title : string
            Title of the plot.
        x : array_like
            List of x coordinates
        y : array_like
            List of y coordinates
        z : array_like
            List of z coordinates
        xlabel : string
            Label of x axis
        ylabel : string
            Label of y axis
        zlabel : string
            Label of z axis
    """
    plt.figure().suptitle(title)
    plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z)
    plt.axis([x[0], x[-1], y[0], y[-1]])
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    plt.colorbar().set_label(zlabel)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: `%matplotlib notebook`

Answer (score 82):

If you use `%pylab inline` you can (on a new line) insert the following command:

```
%pylab inline
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 6)
```

This will set all figures in your document (unless otherwise specified) to be of the size `(10, 6)`, where the first entry is the width and the second is the height.

See this SO post for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17231361/1419668

Comment: simply `figsize(10, 6)` does the job and times easier to remember.

Comment: NameError: name 'figsize' is not defined

Answer (score 71):

This is way I did it:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12, 9) # (w, h)
```

You can define your own sizes.

Comment: `plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] =(12,9) `   also this works

Answer (score 67):

If you're not in an ipython notebook (like the OP), you can also just declare the size when you declare the figure:

```
width = 12
height = 12
plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
```

Comment: Do you have any idea in which units this is measured?

Comment: Units are inches, but YMMV (your display's DPI may not match matplotlib's assumptions).  Also, this won't work in the OP's environment, an iPython Notebook!

Comment: @hobs which version of iPython notebook are you running? it is working for me in Jupyter.

Comment: Doesn't work on mine. The version of the notebook server is 4.2.1. Python 3.5.2, Anaconda 4.1.1 (x86_64)

Comment: Works for me in emacs/ein 20161228.741

Comment: @hobs this works for me in ipython.  My site's ipython is slightly hacked, but I would be very surprised if it didn't work for generic ipython as well.