# Matplotlib chart does not change size after resize in jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am having an issue with resizing a bar chart using matplotlib in jupyter notebook, and even after going through other answered questions ([How to make inline plots in Jupyter Notebook larger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367986/how-to-make-inline-plots-in-jupyter-notebook-larger) and [Plot width settings in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589119/plot-width-settings-in-ipython-notebook)) and using the methods described within the answers to those questions, my bar chart does not change size.

Output before resize:
[image]

Output after resize:
[image]

As you can see, even though the rcParams have clearly changed, the plot still remains the same size. Any pointers as to how I can resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try setting the rc params to the new desired figsize before calling `plt.figure()`?
or put `plt.gcf().set_size_inches(*fig_size)`  before `plt.show()`

Comment: @aorr Yes, using the `plt.gcf().set_size_inches(*fig_size)` resolved my issue. Thank you so much for help!