# set jupyter notebook inlinebackend figsize larger

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I use the jupyter notebook to do plot in python. I set the figsize in my own .mplstyle file with figsize=2.55,1.91, that very small, but suit for my scientific papers. Now I plot the pics in the notebook with my own style file, the picture are too small, how can i make it bigger?

I tried the way here [How to set the matplotlib figure default size in ipython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230797/how-to-set-the-matplotlib-figure-default-size-in-ipython-notebook), it seems doesn't work. I don't want to change the figsize in my style file because I have to save the image with that figsize. How can I display it in notebook with a bigger size?

Answer (score 1):

For all notebooks: put this, with your desired `figsize` in your ipython_kernel_config (for jupyter 5.x and above):

```
c = get_config()
c.InlineBackend.rc.update({"figure.figsize": (12, 10)})
```

You can also do it in the notebook itself:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12, 10)
```