# Change default matplotlib value in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was wondering how you can change the matplotlib.rcParams permanently instead of indicating it every time when you open jupyter notebook. (like change in the profile as the default value).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A short answer, also for personal reference...

I would still prefer *indicating* it in the code though. However it doesn't have to be done for every single parameters as it can be done in one line calling for a *style* file for instance.

Anyway, here are several ways of doing so, from the most *permanent* change to the most *soft* and subtle way of changing the parameters:

### 1. Change default config file

Change the default parameters in `matplotlibrc` file, you can find its location with:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.get_configdir()
```

### 2. Modify iPython profile

Change how matplotlib default options are loaded in iPython by modifying options in `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py`, or wherever your configuraiton file is (`ipython locate profile` to find out) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17231361/5303618) for details)

### 3. Create your own styles

You can create your own custom rcParams files and store them in `.config/matplotlib/stylelib/*.mplstyle` or wherever `os.path.join(matplotlib.get_configdir(), stylelib)` is.

The file should be in the following format, similar to `matplotlibrc`, e.g. `my_dark.mplstyle`:

```
axes.labelcolor: white
axes.facecolor : 333333
axes.edgecolor : white
ytick.color : white
xtick.color : white
text.color : white
figure.facecolor : 0D0D0D
```

This is an example of a style for a dark background with white axes, and white tick labels...

To use it, before your plots, call:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("my_dark")
# Note that matplotlib has already several default styles you can chose from
```

You can overlay styles by using *several* ones at once, the last one overwrites its predecessors' parameters. This can be useful to keep e.g. font variables from a certain style (paper-like, presentation) but simultaneously toggle a dark mode on top, by overwriting all color-related parameters. 
With something like `plt.style.use(["paper_fonts", "my_dark"])`

More info in their [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#).

### 4. Context manager for rc_params

You can also use a **context manager**, this option is great in my opinion, to do something like:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with mpl.rc_context(rc={'text.usetex': True}, fname='screen.rc'):
    plt.plot(x, a)

plt.plot(x, b)
```

Here we used a first set of parameters as defined in the file `screen.rc` then tweak the `text.usetex` value solely for the `plt.plot(x,a)` while `plt.plot(x, b)` will be using another (default here) set of rc parameters.

Again, see [the doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html) for more information.